# implement message handler in rabbitmq to process received messages

Tags: rabbitmq, domain-driven-design

Recently i am trying to use DDD to implement my applications.i use rabbitmq broker to publish my events.
suppose i have 2 domains A B .each of them have its Database.i want to add a record to A database and the A domain should publish an event to insert that record to B database.

In implementation when i insert the record in A database i should call `recordinserted` event from A domain ,but my question is how my B domain should call `messagehandler` to process that message? i mean should i call a thread to listen the `rabbitmq` queue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement the message handling yourself or you could use a service bus.  I have an open source service bus project called Shuttle.Esb:

- [Documentation](http://shuttle.github.io/shuttle-esb/)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Esb)

There are others you could look at if Shuttle.Esb does not resonate with you.